# Are there any problem with consistent among UI elements if I use floating label at Login screen but the others use top left aligned label?

Tags: consistency

I have an issue that needs your help.

Is there any problem with consistency among UI elements if I use a floating label at the log-in screen but the others use a top left-aligned label?
Can you give me resources, references, or researches related to this?

An example in Adobe app:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: This sounds like a technical implementation question, which would be off-topic here. From a UX perspective it doesn't matter as long as they look and function the same. Do you have a specific concern your can show an example of?

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. Below is an example: (sorry I don't know how to add image here) In Adobe: Login Screen: they use floating lable, but in "Add payment method" screen, for example, they use top-left-aligned-label

Comment: We defined a rule for apps: each UI element type have to consistent in color, bgcolor, fonttype, fontsize, fontstyle, shape, elevation, label alignment, states, ... in overall app. So , we are discussing about this issue when some graphics designer want to style as the above Adobe app example.

Comment: Then you should use that list to decide if using a floating label is acceptable. If it ticks all the boxes then it's ok, if any of them fail then it isn't ok.

Comment: I mean the inconsistent with text field style.

Comment: I don't see any labels not aligned to top left... Can you point out which ones you mean?

Answer (score 0):

There is almost no design system or implementation of a software application that is guaranteed to be 100% consistent. And you can even argue whether the design between the two different types of screen is consistent or not because there might be a different style and layout specified for login screens compared to other transactional views and interfaces.

I actually couldn't find much information on [Spectrum](https://spectrum.adobe.com/) (Adobe's Design System) or [Spectrum 2](https://s2.spectrum.adobe.com/) in relation to how page layouts, styles and components are to be applied and different types of workflows, so you'll have to have some inside information to understand why it was designed this way.